# Delete Entity From BDDMockito

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, bdd

I have a `Company` entity and try to test delete operation on it with try to test `MockMVC` and `BDDMockito`.

```
    Company company = new Company();
    company.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
    company.setCompanyName("Test Company");
    company.setAddress("Lake Street, LA");
    company.setWebsiteURL("www.company.com");

    given(companyService.get(company.getId())).willReturn(company);

    mvc.perform(get("/company/" + company.getId())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.response", notNullValue()));

    mvc.perform(delete("/company/" + company.getId())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    mvc.perform(get("/company/" + company.getId())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.response", nullValue()));
```

However, `delete` does not drop company from Mock company service. How can I drop `company` variable from company service after a delete operation?

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing this

```
given(companyService.get(company.getId())).willReturn(company);
```

you are saying mockito that every time that someone calls GET /company/{company_id} it has to return a company, so it does not matter if you previously call DELETE /company/{company_id} you will always get that company

Comment: Yes, I want to drop that entity from mock service after delete request as like: `when delete is performed, than return null`

Comment: I do not understand why you want to do that, because the idea is to see if you can consume a rest service sending some parameters and that is the reason beause you are using mock to avoid actual changes.

Anyway if you still want to do that I am thinking after calling DELETE to do this again, but this time returning null:

given(companyService.get(company.getId())).willReturn(null);